# Prestashop multistore slow search requests (strange long SQL "WHERE p.`id_product` IN ...")

Tags: sql, prestashop, multistore

I have problems with search engine performance in prestashop 1.7.7.6 running as a multistore (10 domains). The shops run fast but sometimes the searches queue up and clog up the system. From what I have been able to determine these are SQL queries in the form of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp.`id_product` FROM `ps_category_product` cp INNER JOIN `ps_category_group` cg ON cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category` INNER JOIN `ps_category` c ON cp.`id_category` = c.`id_category` INNER JOIN `ps_product` p ON cp.`id_product` = p.`id_product`  LEFT JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop
        ON (product_shop.id_product = p.id_product AND product_shop.id_shop = 1) WHERE c.`active` = 1 AND product_shop.`active` = 1 AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "search") AND product_shop.indexed = 1 AND cg.`id_group` =1
```

then:

```
SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity,
                pl.`description_short`, pl.`available_now`, pl.`available_later`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`name`,
             image_shop.`id_image` id_image, il.`legend`, m.`name` manufacturer_name ,( SELECT SUM(weight) FROM ps_search_word sw LEFT JOIN ps_search_index si ON sw.id_word = si.id_word WHERE sw.id_lang = 1 AND sw.id_shop = 1 AND si.id_product = p.id_product AND (sw.word LIKE 'lampa%') ) position,
                DATEDIFF(
                    p.`date_add`,
                    DATE_SUB(
                        "2022-12-08 00:00:00",
                        INTERVAL 30 DAY
                    )
                ) > 0 new, product_attribute_shop.minimal_quantity AS product_attribute_minimal_quantity, IFNULL(product_attribute_shop.`id_product_attribute`,0) id_product_attribute
                FROM ps_product p
                 INNER JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop
        ON (product_shop.id_product = p.id_product AND product_shop.id_shop = 1)
                INNER JOIN `ps_product_lang` pl ON (
                    p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                    AND pl.`id_lang` = 1 AND pl.id_shop = 1 
                )
                LEFT JOIN `ps_product_attribute_shop` product_attribute_shop FORCE INDEX (id_product)
                    ON (p.`id_product` = product_attribute_shop.`id_product` AND product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1 AND product_attribute_shop.id_shop=1)
                 LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available stock
            ON (stock.id_product = `p`.id_product AND stock.id_product_attribute = 0 AND stock.id_shop = 1  AND stock.id_shop_group = 0  )
                LEFT JOIN `ps_manufacturer` m FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)
                    ON m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`
                LEFT JOIN `ps_image_shop` image_shop FORCE INDEX (id_product)
                    ON (image_shop.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND image_shop.cover=1 AND image_shop.id_shop=1)
                LEFT JOIN `ps_image_lang` il ON (image_shop.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = 1)
                WHERE p.`id_product`  IN (1287,2291,2292,2293,2294,6656,6682,6685,6796,9777,9778,12477,12479,12481,12565,12569,13615,14072,14111,17946,17948,18022,18959,18968,19006,19007,19085,19088,19090,19117,19120,19121,19124,19836,20055,21198,21217,21270,21272,21274,22471,23177,24803,24806,24807,24808,24820,24823,24824,24826,24848,24849,24851,24852,24870,24872,24874,24875,24898,24913,24928,24946,24960,25145,25505,25508,25528,26971,27075,27227,27275,27278,27567,28080,29361,29831,29921,30471,30473,30489,30490,30493,30511,30512,30522,30532,30535,30573,30574,30582,30585,30601,30604,30646,30647,30648,30649,30670,30673,30932,30935,30936,30954,30987,30998,31015,31016,31018,31019,31076,31077,31080,31097,31103,31114,32620,32621,32622,32785,32860,32862,32865,32867,32887,32890,32965,32966,32967,32983,33000,33003,33007,33023,33026,33027,33031,33034,33038,33094,33095,33098,33101,33104,33105,33222,33258,33259,33260,33428,34479,34481,34483,34488,34489,34490,34731,34733,34769,34772,35988,35990,35993,35999,36158,36162,36175,36178,36833,36959,38104,38356,38357,38360,38504,38583,39888,39962,39971,39973,40471,40554,41489,41866,42391,42588,42589,42839,42971,43050,43943,44291,44292,44293,44322,44335,44336,44802,44810,44823,44865,44866,44867,44879,44950,44951,44952,44964,44968,44974,45310,45319,45469,45510,45545,45551,45552,45553,45554,45555,45556,45557,45558,45612,45627,45628,45639,45640,45742,45866,45910,45911,45912,45920,45935,45937,45942,45943,46020,46021,46042,46043,46047,46085,46086,46087,46088,46089,46090,46091,46242,46243,46416,46689,46690,47044,47080,47164,47177,47198,47408,47447,47977,47978,47979,48058,48955,48991,49057,49490,49622,49630,49635,49636,49637,49676,49683,49684,49743,49745,49751,49754,49758,49762,50273,50276,50300,50313,50705,50782,50816,50916,51046,51151,51152,51153,51154,51159,51160,51161,51162,51163,51164,51315,51365,51366,51367,51368,51369,51370,51371,51375,51377,51383,51405,51548,51549,51550,51594,51595,51608,51616,51618,51619,51622,51628,51632,51728,51739,52271,52273,52274,52532,52533,52534,52535,52541,52613,52743,52756,52797,52809,52854,52855,52981,53158,53159,53160,53500,53503,53504,53505,53506,53665,53666,54387,54388,54394,54395,54401,54402,54403,54435,54445,54446,54447,54448,54449,54450,54465,54541,54570,54579,54591,54751,54755,54759,54763,54766,54769,54771,54772,54773,54774,54775,54776,54777,54784,54785,54786,54787,54788,55168,55182,55193,55319,55320,55345,55355,55463,55464,55466,55467,55600,55945,55946,55947,55948,55949,55950,56002,56003,56004,56005,56006,56008,56009,56047,56048,56049,56053,56139,56186,56265,56284,56285,56413,56414,56631,56632,56649,56767,56840,56844,56845,56849,56861,56862,56865,56868,56869,56937,56941,56985,57038,57144,57148,57164,57165,57166,57178,57194,57277,57304,57310,57323,57327,57328,57415,57416,57417,57418,57420,57451,57460,57468,57471,57472,57473,57612,57625,57645,57704,57705,57707,58083,58084,58317,58558,58643,58644,58645,58766,58767,58850,58909,58964,58983,59020,59070,59071,59091,59098,59099,59182,59211,59398,59400,59401,59402,59403,59404,59405,59406,59462,59463,59745,59855,59856,59857,59858,59859,59877,59878,59904,59905,59908,59909,59951,59961,59989,59990,59991,59992,59993,59994,60151,60204,60208,60211,60212,60213,60214,60221,60231,60235,60267,60268,60269,60414,60419,60443,60520,60521,60548,60551,60552,60572,60577,60578,60704,60712,60717,60718,60719,60720,60721,60799,60971,60972,60974,60975,60989,60995,60996,60999,61000,61004,61040,61046,61055,61063,61081,61148,61149,61150,61151,61152,61153,61154,61155,61207,61209,61215,61216,61224,61234,61245,61269,61270,61279,61280,61365,61388,61399,61471,61509,61510,61511,61515,61518,61519,61520,61521,61544,61558,61560,61561,61562,61565,61580,61586,61694,61697,61732,61733,61734,61760,61761,61889,61891,62097,62108,62114,62116,62123,62124,62125,62128,62129,62133,62141,62144,62145,62146,62147,62189,62217,62235,62368,62426,62469,62541,62552,62626,62627,62628,62629,62630,62631,62729,62769,62806,62808,62810,62876,62877,62878,62879,62895,62935,62936,62937,62940,62945,63076,63078,63079,63080,63081,63082,63090,63091,63092,63095,63097,63099,63100,63126,63134,63138,63147,63152,63159,63223,63231,63236,63241,63242,63253,63261,63265,63274,63304,63305,63307,63340,63390,63407,63409,63601,63604,63605,63606,63607,63709,63710,63711,63712,63714,63715,63716,63730,63731,63732,63733,63734,63735,63736,63738,63739,63740,63788,63789,63790,63791,63792,63794,63795,63797,63798,63799,63800,63801,63802,63852,63853,63860,63867,63876,63888,63917,64080,64134,64143,64152,64153,64154,64155,64164,64165,64166,64167,64168,64268,64269,64270,64271,64272,64273,64274,64275,64276,64278,64279,64280,64281,64282,64283,64284,64285,64286,64287,64288,64289,64290,64291,64292,64293,64294,64295,64296,64297,64298,64299,64300,64301,64302,64303,64304,64305,64307,64308,64311,64312,64313,64314,64315,64316,64317,64318,64319,64320,64321,64322,64323,64324,64325,64326,64327,64328,64329,64330,64331,64332,64333,64334,64335,64336,64337,64338,64351,64352,64353,64354,64356,64357,64386,64416,64417,64418,64419,64420,64421,64468,64469,64470,64486,64487,64488,64489,64490,64491,64492,64493,64494,64495,64496,64497,64498,64499,64500,64529,64530,64531,64532,64533,64535,64536,64538,64539,64541,64542,64547,64548,64552,64553,64554,64555,64556,64557,64558,64559,64560,64561,64562,64563,64564,64565,64566,64567,64568,64569,64570,64571,64572,64573,64574,64575,64576,64577,64578,64579,64580,64581,64582,64583,64584,64585,64586,64587,64588,64589,64704,64838,64839,64850,64851,64852,64853,64854,64855,64856,64857,64858,64859,64860,64861,64862,64863,64864,64865,64866,64916,64917,64918,64919,64920,64921,64922,64931,64932,64933,64934,64943,64944,64945,65052,65053,65054,65055,65056,65057,65058,65059,65060,65061,65062,65063,65064,65065,65066,65067,65068,65069,65072,65073,65074,65075,65078,65079,65080,65081,65083,65085,65086,65087,65088,65089,65090,65091,65092,65093,65094,65095,65096,65097,65099,65100,65101,65102,65103,65104,65105,65106,65118,65119,65121,65125,65127,65145,65146,65147,65151,65152,65153,65154,65155,65158,65160,65164,65165,65166,65167,65168,65169,65181,65182,65183,65184,65185,65188,65189,65190,65191,65192,65193,65211,65238,65239,65240,65242,65271,65349,65396,65397,65398,65399,65400,65401,65402,65403,65404,65405,65406,65407,65408,65409,65410,65411,65412,65425,65439,65440,65441,65442,65443,65444,65445,65446,65447,65448,65449,65450,65451,65452,65454,65472,65473,65474,65475,65478,65479,65480,65481,65482,65485,65486,65487,65488,65489,65490,65492,65493,65494,65516,65517,65518,65519,65520,65521,65522,65523,65524,65525,65526,65532,65533,65534,65536,65537,65538,65550,65551,65552,65553,65554,65566,65570,65574,65575,65576,65585,65586,65587,65589,65590,65591,65594,65595,65598,65599,65603,65604,65612,65614,65616,65626,65629,65638,65639,65657,65658,65659,65662,65663,65666,65669,65670,65674,65675,65676,65677,65681,65683,65685,65686,65702,65703,65704,65705,65706,65713,65714,65715,65716,65717,65718,65719,65720,65724,65729,65809,65815,65820,65838,65839,65849,65853,65860,65914,65919,65920,65923,65926,65927,65928,65929,65930,65931,65932,65933,65934,65935,65936,65937,65938,65940,65941,65942,65943,65955,65956,65957,65958,65959,65960,65961,65962,65963,65964,65965,65966,65967,65981,65982,65986,65987,65993,65994,65995,65996,65997,65998,65999,66000,66001,66002,66003,66004,66005,66006,66007,66008,66017,66019,66020,66021,66022,66024,66025,66026,66027,66028,66034,66035,66036,66037,66046,66047,66048,66049,66050,66051,66052,66053,66054,66055,66056,66057,66058,66059,66060,66061,66062,66063,66064,66065,66066,66067,66068,66069,66070,66071,66072,66079,66080,66081,66082,66090,66091,66092,66093,66098,66101,66104,66110,66117,66118,66121,66122,66123,66124,66125,66126,66127,66128,66129,66138,66139,66143,66144,66145,66146,66147,66148,66155,66157,66162,66163,66164,66165,66182,66183,66192,66213,66214,66219,66270,66271,66273,66274,66276,66277,66278,66288,66289,66291,66292,66295,66296,66299,66300,66305,66306,66307,66308,66309,66310,66311,66312,66313,66314,66315,66316,66317,66318,66320,66321,66322,66324,66332,66333,66334,66335,66336,66337,66354,66355,66356,66357,66375,66376,66388,66389,66390,66391,66392,66393,66394,66395,66396,66397,66398,66399,66400,66401,66402,66405,66406,66407,66408,66409,66422,66423,66424,66425,66428,66429,66430,66431,66432,66433,66443,66444,66445,66456,66457,66470,66471,66472,66473,66474,66483,66484,66485,66486,66487,66489,66490,66491,66503,66504,66506,66511,66526,66559,66560,66561,66562,66563,66569,66570,66571,66572,66573,66577,66578,66579,66580,66581,66582,66583,66584,66585,66586,66631,66632,66633,66634,66648,66649,66650,66651,66652,66653,66654,66655,66656,66657,66658,66659,66709,66710,66711,66712,66713,66714,66715,66716,66730,66731,66738,66739,66740,66741,66742,66748,66749,66750,66751,66757,66758,66759,66764,66765,66766,66770,66771,66782,66783,66784,66785,66786,66787,66788,66791,66792,66793,66794,66795,66798,66799,66815,66816,66817,66818,66822,66823,66826,66827,66828,66831,66832,66833,66834,66835,66836,66837,66838,66839,66840,66841,66842,66843,66844,66845,66851,66852,66860,66861,66862,66863,66864,66865,66866,66867,66868,66873,66874,66883,66884,66891,66892,66894,66895,66903,66904,66905,66906,66907,66922,66932,66940,66943,66944,66945,66946,66951,66952,66953,66960,66961,66962,66975,66976,66977,66978,66979,66984,66987,66988,66989,66990,66991,66992,66993,66994,67014,67015,67018,67019,67025,67026,67033,67034,67035,67036,67037,67038,67039,67040,67041,67042,67043,67044,67045,67046,67047,67065,67073,67074,67075,67162,67170,67181,67182,67185,67186,67187,67193,67194,67196,67202,67203,67204,67205,67206,67215,67217,67218,67219,67221,67222,67231,67233,67235,67250,67251,67252,67253,67254,67255,67256,67258,67261,67270,67282,67291,67292,67293,67338,67339,67340,67341,67342,67343,67344,67345,67346,67347,67348,67351,67352,67355,67356,67359,67360,67523,67524,67532,67533,67534,67535,67536,67537,67538,67539,67541,67542,67543,67544,67563,67564,67565,67589,67590,67591,67592,67609,67610,67611,67613,67633,67642,67643,67644,67650,67651,67656,67657,67659,67661,67691,67693,67694,67725,67726,67728,67729,67731,67732,67736,67737,67738,67739,67740,67741,67747,67748,67751,67752,67755,67756,67759,67760,67763,67764,67767,67768,67771,67772,67809,67817,67818,67819,67820,67909,67910,67913,67914,67915,67916,67917,67921,67922,67923,67924,67925,67926,67927,67928,67929,67930,67931,67932,67933,67934,67935,67936,67937,67938,67939,67940,67941,67942,67943,67944,67945,67946,67947,67949,67951,67952,67953,67954,67955,67959,67961,67962,67963,67964,67965,67966,67967,67968,67969,67971,67972,67973,67974,67978,67984,67985,67986,67987,67991,67995,67996,67998,67999,68000,68005,68006,68011,68012,68014,68015,68016,68017,68021,68022,68023,68024,68025,68029,68030,68031,68032,68033,68036,68037,68047,68048,68049,68050,68051,68054,68058,68059,68060,68064,68065,68066,68074,68075,68076,68077,68078,68114,68115,68118,68119,68127,68141,68144,68145,68146,68151,68152,68156,68157,68159,68160,68165,68166,68170,68171,68172,68175,68176,68178,68180,68181,68182,68183,68184,68186,68193,68194,68200,68203,68204,68207,68208,68209,68213,68214,68218,68219,68220,68223,68225,68228,68229,68230,68235,68241,68263,68289,68290,68292,68293,68296,68297,68298,68299,68300,68301,68302,68303,68304,68305,68306,68307,68308,68309,68311,68312,68313,68314,68315,68316,68317,68318,68319,68320,68321,68322,68323,68325,68326,68328,68331,68332,68333,68336,68337,68338,68339,68340,68341,68342,68343,68344,68346,68347,68348,68349,68350,68351,68352,68353,68354,68355,68356,68357,68358,68359,68360,68361,68362,68363,68364,68365,68368,68369,68370,68371,68372,68373,68374,68375,68376,68377,68378,68379,68380,68381,68382,68383,68384,68385,68386,68387,68388,68389,68390,68391,68392,68393,68400,68403,68404,68408,68409,68410,68411,68425,68426,68427,68428,68429,68430,68432,68449,68450,68451,68452,68453,68454,68480,68482,68483,68484,68497,68498,68500,68531,68532,68533,68536,68537,68538,68539,68540,68541,68542,68543,68544,68547,68554,68555,68557,68558,68559,68562,68563,68564,68565,68576,68577,68578,68579,68580,68609,68610,68611,68612,68657,68658,68659,68661,68662,68663,68664,68665,68666,68667,68671,68674,68675,68717,68718,68719,68720,68721,68722,68723,68771,68772,68773,68774,68775,68776,68777,68781,68782,68783,68784,68785,68786,68787,68788,68789,68790,68791,68792,68793,68794,68795,68796,68797,68798,68799,68817,68818,68819,68820,68821,68822,68823,68824,68825,68830,68831,68840,68841,68842,68843,68844,68845,68868,68869,68870,68871,68872,68926,68927,68928,68933,68936,68967,68968,68969,68970,68971,68972,68973,68974,68979,68980,68981,68982,68986,68987,68988,68989,68990,68991,68992,68993,68994,68995,68996,69013,69014,69015,69016,69017,69078,69085,69086,69087,69088,69093,69101,69124,69128,69132,69133,69143,69152,69157,69158,69161,69165,69166,69167,69168,69169,69170,69171,69172,69177,69190,69194,69196,69197,69198,69201,69202,69212,69213,69216,69217,69219,69220,69222,69223,69224,69225,69229,69230,69233,69234,69235,69239,69240,69241,69242,69243,69244,69247,69248,69249,69251,69252,69254,69255,69257,69258,69260,69261,69262,69263,69268,69269,69285,69288,69291,69292,69296,69299,69300,69301,69302,69303,69304,69305,69306,69307,69308,69309,69331,69332,69333,69334,69335,69336,69340,69341,69342,69343,69344,69345,69350,69351,69352,69353,69354,69355,69358,69362,69363,69364,69369,69371,69374,69375,69376,69392,69395,69396,69397,69398,69399,69400,69401,69402,69403,69421,69422,69423,69424,69425,69426,69434,69435,69443,69444,69445,69446,69449,69450,69456,69457,69460,69461,69475,69476,69477,69478,69479,69480,69495,69502,69506,69507,69508,69509,69510,69511,69513,69516,69519,69520,69521,69522,69523,69524,69525,69526,69527,69528,69529,69530,69531,69532,69534,69535,69542,69543,69550,69552,69553,69556,69562,69563,69564,69565,69567,69570,69571,69572,69573,69574,69575,69576,69577,69578,69579,69580,69581,69582,69583,69584,69585,69586,69587,69588,69589,69590,69591,69603,69604,69605,69606,69607,69608,69609,69615,69616,69617,69618,69619,69620,69621,69623,69640,69678,69679,69680,69683,69684,69687,69691,69692,69694,69696,69697,69704,69705,69706,69707,69708,69756,69757,69760,69761,69762,69765,69766,69784,69785,69797,69798,69800,69802,69803,69806,69807,69808,69809,69810,69811,69812,69813,69814,69816,69817,69818,69819,69831,69832,69840,69842,69847,69848,69859,69860,69866,69871,69872,69873,69874,69875,69876,69877,69878,69895,69896,69897,69898,69903,69910,69911,69912,69913,69917,69923,69924,69925,69927,69928,69929,69934,69935,69936,69945,69950,69951,69952,69953,69957,69961,69962,69966,69967,69971,69972,69973,69974,69975,69976,69977,69978,69979,69980,69981,69982,69992,69997,69998,70008,70009,70020,70021,70022,70023,70026,70029,70032,70035,70036,70037,70040,70041,70044,70047,70056,70057,70058,70059,70060,70061,70062,70063,70064,70065,70066,70067,70068,70069,70070,70071,70072,70073,70086,70087,70088,70089,70094,70098,70102,70114,70134,70135,70136,70137,70138,70139,70140,70141,70142,70172,70175,70179,70181,70182,70183,70211,70212,70227,70228,70236,70237,70238,70239,70240,70241,70242,70243,70244,70245,70247,70248,70259,70260,70262,70270,70271,70272,70273,70274,70275,70276,70277,70278,70283,70284,70285,70286,70287,70288,70293,70294,70295,70296,70297,70298,70300,70301,70302,70303,70304,70305,70306,70307,70308,70309,70310,70311,70312,70313,70314,70315,70316,70317,70318,70319,70320,70321,70322,70323,70324,70325,70326,70327,70328,70329,70330,70331,70332,70334,70335,70336,70337,70338,70339,70340,70341,70342,70343,70344,70345,70346,70347,70348,70350,70351,70352,70353,70359,70360,70365,70366,70369,70370,70381,70382,70386,70387,70388,70389,70392,70393,70396,70397,70401,70402,70403,70404,70405,70406,70407,70408,70409,70410,70411,70412,70413,70414,70415,70416,70419,70420,70423,70425,70426,70427,70428,70429,70431,70432,70435,70436,70437,70438,70439,70440,70441,70442,70445,70446,70447,70448,70449,70450,70451,70452,70453,70454,70455,70456,70457,70458,70459,70461,70480,70481,70482,70483,70484,70485,70486,70487,70488,70489,70490,70492,70495,70496,70497,70498,70508,70509,70510,70511,70512,70513,70514,70515,70516,70520,70521,70522,70523,70525,70526,70527,70528,70529,70530,70531,70532,70533,70534,70535,70536,70537,70538,70539,70540,70541,70542,70543,70544,70545,70546,70547,70548,70549,70550,70551,70552,70554,70567,70568,70573,70574,70576,70579,70580,70584,70585,70588,70589,70590,70591,70592,70593,70594,70595,70596,70597,70598,70599,70602,70603,70604,70605,70606,70607,70608,70609,70610,70611,70612,70613,70614,70617,70618,70619,70620,70621,70622,70623,70624,70625,70626,70628,70629,70630,70631,70632,70633,70634,70635,70636,70637,70638,70639,70640,70641,70642,70643,70644,70645,70650,70651,70654,70655,70656,70657,70658,70659,70660,70661,70662,70663,70664,70665,70666,70667,70668,70669,70670,70671,70672,70673,70674,70676,70677,70678,70681,70682,70685,70686,70687,70688,70689,70690,70691,70692,70693,70694,70698,70699,70700,70701,70702,70703,70704,70705,70706,70707,70708,70709,70710,70716,70735,70736,70737,70738,70752,70759,70760,70761,70762,70763,70764,70765,70766,70767,70768,70769,70770,70771,70772,70773,70774,70987,70988,70989,70990,70991,70993,70994,70995,70996,70997,70998,70999,71004,71005,71006,71007,71008,71009,71012,71013,71014,71016,71025,71026,71027,71028,71029,71030,71031,71032,71033,71034,71035,71036,71037,71039,71040,71041,71042,71043,71045,71046,71047,71048,71056,71062,71063,71064,71065,71067,71068,71070,71071,71072,71073,71074,71075,71076,71077,71083,71084,71085,71086,71087,71088,71097,71099,71100,71101,71102,71103,71104,71105,71106,71107,71108,71109,71110,71111,71112,71113,71114,71115,71117,71118,71119,71120,29443,29452,65254,65255,65256,65257,66781,68929,68930,68931,12483,12485,12487,12489,30564,30567,30568,36229,37127,37128,37129,37131,37132,37148,37149,37150,37151,37154,37155,37156,37157,37160,37161,37162,37163,37164,37165,66983,56470,64217,64218,12762,12763,12764,12765,20118,20119,27640,27656,36769,36770,56707,59127,59128,59728,59731,62539,63370,65850,65854,65858,4721,6792,18401,18402,18404,18406,30655,45106,45121,45126,49685,49686,65082,67504,67505,67506,68810,68813,68814,68828,68838,68839,68847,69076,4733,4751,38113,48130,48950,58666,63650,65354,30082,30083,30084,30103,30104,30106,39624,42716,42717,42718,48471,63697,65272,69614,24853,24855,24901,27641,27642,27654,27655,27657,30249,30554,30612,30637,34472,44280,44445,44446,45127,45128,46837,46843,47183,47184,49047,50251,50293,50308,50320,50331,68254,68255,14011,14012,14022,14035,17926,17928,18810,18812,21199,25523,27356,48912,49074,49075,49298,49299,52512,52513,52644,52690,53628,53629,53630,53632,55085,55529,55530,56197,57532,57693,58541,58544,58885,58886,59126,59948,59949,60023,60028,60029,60033,60034,60315,60316,60321,61914,61915,61946,61999,62000,62074,62204,62205,63247,63248,63347,63669,63670,65578,65579,65795,65796,65797,65798,65806,65807,65818,65819,65823,66108,66179,66180,66181,66206,66207,66208,66282,66283,2287,2288,2289,2290,2311,4750,18390,20031,20765,20767,27250,27931,27932,27933,38584,42982,44275,44276,45102,51003,51603,51803,52632,57706,58101,58585,61256,61367,61368,61369,62412,62413,62549,62614,62615,62617,62618,66728,66736,66802,66803,66804,66805,66806,66807,66808,66809,66888,66941,67225,67226,67811,67812,67813,67814,67822,67823,67824,67825,68004,41300,41301,41304,41305,41306,41308,41309,42422,42423,46714,46715,46716,46717,46724,46725,51316,51317,52189,56434,56437,56503,56790,58662,59218,59265,59266,59267,59317,59318,59319,59320,59321,59322,59323,59324,59325,59326,60502,61444,61445,61447,61448,61450,61451,61460,61461,61462,61463,61490,61491,61492,61493,61494,64969,65258,65259,65260,65261,65262,65263,65264,65265,65287,65288,65584,65726,65727,65728,65730,65731,65732,65789,65790,65791,65792,65793,65794,66077,66088,66383,66384,66385,66467,66468,66469,66480,66481,66482,66554,66564,66896,66897,66898,66899,66900,67134,67135,67584,67585,67586,67587,67588,68738,68739,69661,69837,69838,15642,34726,34728,34760,34762,39665,44425,48922,48923,49050,49051,49052,49055,49056,60347,60348,60349,60350,60351,60352,60568,65123,65124,65347,65350,65351,66514,66529,66985,66986,68002,68003,68009,68010,68232,68714,68715,68716,18574,23196,36963,36965,36976,36994,36996,41302,41303,42480,42584,42585,42586,42587,44545,44815,44816,46383,46726,46727,49058,49059,49060,49656,49659,52321,52567,52570,52571,54443,54444,55826,56045,56046,57337,57339,58371,58656,58938,59297,59298,59299,59300,59302,60027,60032,60035,60036,60037,60038,60326,60328,60336,60337,60549,60550,60553,60554,60556,60557,60558,60569,60574,60575,60612,60616,60624,60626,60630,61201,61275,61387,61466,61467,61468,61533,61535,61568,61571,61587,62240,63066,63067,63068,63069,63101,63102,63245,64696,65338,65340,65341,65342,65596,65597,65600,65601,65602,65624,65625,65628,65655,65656,65667,65688,65747,65748,65751,65752,65760,65761,65762,65764,65765,65767,65768,65770,65771,65773,65774,65780,65781,65782,65783,65784,65785,65800,65801,65803,65804,65816,65817,65821,65822,65826,65827,65828,65830,65832,65871,65873,65878,65907,65912,65913,65915,65916,65917,65918,66016,66018,66029,66030,66031,66032,66033,66074,66075,66076,66078,66085,66086,66087,66089,66102,66103,66166,66167,66168,66169,66170,66171,66172,66173,66176,66177,66178,66186,66187,66188,66189,66204,66209,66210,66211,66280,66281,66290,66293,66294,66323,66325,66536,66537,66538,66539,66540,66541,66542,66543,66544,66545,66969,66970,66971,66972,66973,66974,67022,67023,67059,67067,67129,67130,67131,67132,67183,67184,67188,67189,67190,67191,67192,67223,67224,67227,67228,67229,67237,67238,67239,67240,67241,67499,67500,67501,67502,67503,67508,67509,67528,67529,67530,67612,67614,67615,67617,67619,67621,67622,67624,67626,67631,67632,67635,67636,67637,67639,67640,67641,67647,67648,67653,67654,67655,67665,67666,67667,67668,67669,67671,67672,67673,67674,67675,67679,67680,67681,67683,67684,67692,67695,67696,67699,67700,67701,67702,67703,67705,67706,67708,67709,67711,67712,67714,67715,67716,67718,67719,67720,67722,67723,67724,67776,67777,67780,67781,67783,67784,67785,67787,67788,67789,67793,67794,67795,67796,67798,67799,67800,67801,67802,67804,67805,67806,67807,67827,67828,67829,67831,67832,67833,67835,67836,67837,67841,67842,67845,67846,67847,67848,67852,67853,67855,67856,67857,67860,67861,67862,67864,67865,67867,67868,67869,67870,67872,67873,67874,67876,67877,67878,67880,67881,67882,67884,67885,67886,67889,67890,67891,67893,67894,67895,67896,67898,67899,67900,67901,67903,67904,67905,67906,67979,67980,67981,67982,67989,67990,68041,68042,68080,68081,68082,68083,68084,68085,68086,68087,68088,68090,68091,68092,68093,68094,68096,68097,68098,68099,68100,68101,68102,68103,68104,68105,68106,68107,68129,68130,68131,68132,68133,68134,68135,68136,68137,68138,68192,68199,68201,68202,68205,68206,68264,68277,68278,68279,68280,68285,68286,68327,68545,68566,68567,68568,68569,68570,68571,68572,68573,68574,68575,68724,68725,68726,68727,68728,68729,68730,68731,68732,68733,68734,68735,68736,68737,68763,68764,68875,68876,68877,68878,68879,68880,68881,68882,68883,68884,68885,68886,68918,68919,68920,68921,68922,68923,68924,68925,68938,68939,68940,68941,68942,68943,68944,68945,68946,68947,68948,68949,68950,68951,68952,68953,69005,69006,69007,69008,69009,69010,69011,69012,69042,69043,69044,69045,69046,69047,69048,69049,69094,69095,69096,69097,69103,69104,69105,69121,69122,69123,69125,69126,69127,69129,69130,69134,69135,69136,69137,69139,69140,69141,69142,69145,69146,69147,69148,69150,69151,69153,69154,69155,69156,69159,69160,69162,69163,69164,69174,69175,69176,69178,69179,69180,69181,69183,69184,69186,69187,69188,69195,69218,69232,69238,69245,69246,69273,69276,69277,69279,69280,69281,69282,69293,69294,69295,69297,69313,69314,69315,69316,69317,69318,69319,69320,69348,69349,69408,69409,69427,69428,69431,69432,69436,69437,69440,69454,69455,69466,69467,69468,69469,69512,69540,69541,69544,69545,69548,69549,69559,69566,69568,69569,69592,69593,69594,69595,69622,69796,69801,69804,69820,69825,69826,69827,69833,69834,69849,69854,69855,69856,69879,69884,69885,69886,69888,69889,69890,69891,69899,69904,69905,69906,69918,69919,69920,69941,69942,69943,69944,69946,69947,69948,69949,69988,69989,69990,69991,69993,69994,69995,69996,70004,70005,70006,70007,70016,70017,70018,70019,70091,70092,70093,70095,70096,70097,70099,70100,70101,70103,70104,70105,70107,70108,70109,70111,70112,70113,70116,70117,70118,70119,70120,70121,70122,70124,70125,70126,70127,70214,70215,70216,70217,70218,70219,70220,70221,70250,70251,70252,70254,70255,70256,70264,70280,70281,70282,70290,70291,70292,70358,70364,70368,70470,70471,70473,70474,70475,70477,70478,70479,70600,70646,70683,70684,70711,70717,70718,70740,70741,70742,70746,70747,70748,70749,70753,70754,70755,70756,71000,71010,71011,71017,71018,71019,71022,71023,71024,71080,71081,71082,71089,71090,71093,71094,71123,71124,71125,71126,71128,71129,71130,71132,1784,4196,4260,4680,4682,4730,5130,6335,6604,6828,6832,6838,6844,6865,6866,6867,6868,6869,6870,6871,6872,8777,9851,10557,12415,12448,12498,12511,12513,12564,12568,12591,12617,12618,12643,12649,12732,12738,12741,12742,13620,13627,13629,13630,13648,13659,13662,13663,13669,13672,13673,13696,13809,13842,13915,13918,13927,14018,14046,14049,14062,14066,14100,14103,14121,14122,14131,14134,14510,14522,14525,14526,14713,14716,14718,14721,14780,14781,14784,14806,14807,14833,14899,14912,14970,17947,17960,17994,17999,18001,18002,18005,18025,18026,18159,18160,18585,18803,18819,18821,18823,18859,18886,18889,18890,18931,18934,18940,18969,18972,19005,19008,19009,19013,19016,19108,19111,19112,19119,19122,19123,19129,19132,19137,19266,20013,20019,20058,20059,20091,20092,20194,20202,20209,20210,20211,20219,20421,20430,20435,20437,20440,20718,20719,20720,20733,20777,20789,20989,21037,21038,21052,21189,21325,21326,21329,21330,21348,21359,22034,22154,22306,22443,23281,23284,24108,24121,24192,24442,24514,24929,24945,24949,25509,25529,25531,25532,25704,26317,26321,26332,26335,26336,26449,26583,26952,26968,27013,27072,27369,27378,27396,27397,27400,27404,27407,27408,27409,27473,27476,27477,27485,27557,27558,27560,27561,27570,27585,27586,27590,27591,27594,27603,27606,27607,27610,27611,27614,27712,27731,27734,27741,27770,27828,27829,27836,27837,27967,28001,28005,28076,28079,28194,28330,28383,28444,28448,28931,29620,29623,29627,29631,29635,30467,30510,30513,30520,30521,30548,30572,30575,30668,30669,30686,30687,30931,30952,30953,30955,30956,31031,31032,31033,31034,31042,31043,31074,31075,31078,31079,31093,31094,31095,31096,31943,32980,32981,32982,33164,33165,33176,33177,33194,33195,33227,33228,33272,33275,33294,33297,33298,33307,33313,33411,33416,33429,33445,33449,33451,34358,36223,36224,36375,36771,36803,36821,36831,36832,36836,36839,36844,36849,36851,36873,36877,36879,36880,36883,36892,36895,36896,36899,36916,36919,36920,36928,37015,37018,37019,37022,37084,37087,37092,37262,37410,38069,38070,38071,38072,38073,38074,38081,38084,38094,38096,38097,38098,38101,38102,38108,38114,38115,38120,38121,38122,38124,38125,38126,38143,38147,38148,38149,38154,38155,38158,38176,38177,38178,38293,38299,38300,38338,38339,38342,38343) 
                GROUP BY product_shop.id_product
                ORDER BY  position desc
                LIMIT 0,10
```

Is it normal? **In particular long part of "WHERE p.`id_product`  IN (1287,2291,... ".** This part was much longer - I shortened it for the purpose of the question

Comment: I guess it's normal. PrestaShop multistore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is performed in the **find()** method of the **Search()** class, its purpose, as you might imagine, is to return searched products.

Being a core query, there is not much you can do except debug it in a SQL client (maybe you are missing some index in DB tables ?) / rewrite the method to suit your needs, upgrade the MySql server resources for better performances or use an external search provider that might help you bypassing the native search.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that it's just a very long query, slow query but not an error. I migrated website to dedicated server. Thank You for your help.